# Problems with legend in DEM raster

Tags: raster, r, legend

This is a follow up question to this one: [Addressing just the outermost cells in a raster?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/327788/addressing-just-the-outermost-cells-in-a-raster) 
In this question you can find all the code and the data.

To summarize:

I have a DEM raster masked to the outlines of some glaciers. The raster is cut into three different masks: glacier-adjacent cells (outside the glacier), glacier margin cells (glacier border cells) und inner glacier cells. I used the code provided by @obrl_soil to cut the raster and it worked.

However, when I plot the three results simultaneously, I get this result (see picture below). 
It seems to me, that every class has a slightly different opinion on what there elevation is. Is this just a plotting error that I overlooked or is there something wrong with the code?

[image]

Comment: Seems like you have three different rasters with three different ranges of values. You may simply have to set the range of values manually when plotting.

Comment: I know its probably a very simple question, but how would I do that? I've looked into adjusting axes with the base plot and found not much. And with ggplot I'm not familiar enough to even plot one raster.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4316692/how-can-i-create-raster-plots-with-the-same-colour-scale-in-r